# How to create a checkBoxGroup under a menuItem in shiny dashboard sidebar?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shinydashboard

I'd like to build a dashboard sidebar that has maybe 3 menuItems and when a menuItem is selected a checkBoxGroup will expand below and the user can select any number of options. How would I go about this?

Here's the relevant parts of my code that I currently have.

```
# ui.R
dashboardSidebar(
    # I need a header to say Select a Dataset
    # I want the menuItems to be selectable but 
    menuItem("Dataset 1", newTab = FALSE),
    menuItem("Dataset 2", newTab = FALSE),
    menuItem("Dataset 3", newTab = FALSE),
    # not sure where to put uiOutput so that it appears below
    #    the selected menuItem
    uiOutput("features")
)

# server.R
dataset <- reactive({
    df <- read.csv()
    return(df)
})
output$features <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput("features", "Select features to plot: ",
        colnames(df))
})
```

Comment: You will want to explore `renderUI` and `outputUI` which would be dependent on the other input.  Make an attempt with some code and then we can help you understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do. However issue with that is you have to click menuItem for Features, click somewhere else for it to populate. I am trying to solve that issue right now. You also have to called dataset() like a function, not df.

```
# ui.R
header <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title ="Data Frame Features", titleWidth = 350)
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
sidebarMenu(
    # I need a header to say Select a Dataset
    # I want the menuItems to be selectable but 
    menuItem("Dataset 1", newTab = FALSE),
    menuItem("Dataset 2", newTab = FALSE),
    menuItem("Dataset 3", newTab = FALSE),
    menuItem("Dataframe Features",tabName = "features", icon = icon("th"), uiOutput("features"), selected = TRUE)
)
)

body <- dashboardBody(
tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "something")
)   

dashboardPage(
  header,
  sidebar,
  body      
) 

# server.R
dataset <- reactive({
    df <- read.csv()
    return(df)
})
output$features <- renderUI({
    checkboxGroupInput("features", "Select features to plot: ", choices= colnames(dataset()), selected = colnames(dataset()))
})
```